# What is the value if the key in .putExtra("key",boolean) does not exist

Tags: android, android-intent

What will the value be if I use `getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("key")` without doing the `.putExtra("key",boolean)` method?

it doesn't accept `!= null` because it's boolean so any gist?

Comment: At a guess, false. :)

Comment: there will be an error, you could test it yourself..

Comment: I don't understand why the minuses, I thought stackoverflow is nice to newbies but sorry if I made a mistake

Comment: @Bryan Probably because one could find the answer to this question easily by searching the web... ;)

Comment: I always search the net before I ask here, and I wouldn't have posted here if I found an answer to my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My solution :

```
boolean defaultValue = false;
boolean yourValue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(YOUR_EXTRA, defaultValue);
```

If you do not make putExtra, your intent will have the default value that you have determined.

I hope I have helped you!

Answer (score 1):

According to [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getBoolean%28java.lang.String%29)

public boolean getBoolean (String key)

Added in API level 1
Returns the value associated with the given key, or **false if no mapping of the desired type exists for the given key.**

So it will return false.

Comment: the code I posted gave me an error so that is not the reference that is appropriate here

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old post, but I guess better late than never. Something like this should work:

```
Boolean booleanValue = false; // Set default value
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle.containsKey("key")) { // Check if key exists
    booleanValue = bundle.getBoolean("key"); // Update variable accordingly
}
```

If you want to be even more terse about it:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
Boolean booleanValue = bundle.containsKey("key") ? bundle.getBoolean("key") : false;
```